# Good PowerShell guide, getting started through more advanced usage

Tags: windows, command-line, automation, powershell, script

Does anyone have a really good tutorial or getting started guide for Microsoft's PowerShell? I'm a long time Linux/Unix user, and very familiar with scripting languages, command-line usage with bash, ksh and zsh. I'm an intermediate Ruby programmer, and have used all these tools for command-line file management and automation tasks.

I would love a "PowerShell for Bash Experts" guide if such a thing exists, or is on that level of detail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Getting Started: [Windows PowerShell Getting Started Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh857337.aspx)
- Programming with Powershell: [Windows PowerShell Programmer's Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd835506(VS.85).aspx)
- Advanced PowerShell: [A Guide To PowerShell's Advanced Functions](http://huddledmasses.org/a-guide-to-advanced-functions/)

Comment: The second link to MSDN there - Windows Powershell Programmer's Guide, looks to be broken ...

Comment: As a possible replacement to the second link, I found a link on MSDN labelled [Windows Powershell Programmer's Guide](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=89596).  I never saw where the link used to go, but the title seems to match.  Also, the Guide in the first link appears to be a subset of this one.

Answer (score 4):

I've found this guide to be extremely helpful. Mastering Powershell - http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebook/

It's a free E-Book by a Powershell MVP that is well written.

Mike

Comment: +1, I also found this one very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I got started using the tutorial on [powershellpro](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/tutorial-windows-powershell-console/).

My only complaints are:

- The navigation is hard to use (list of links on the right hand side)
- There are a few errors and typos throughout. Although if you're an astute reader, you'll notice right away.

The teaching techniques I found useful were when they show how to do a task in both PowerShell and through regular Windows GUI (like MMC) and when they describe real-world uses for some of the scripts or commands.

Answer (score 1):

I found this is a very good starter guide. The eBook is [free for download](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/effective-windows-powershell-the-free-ebook/).

Answer (score 0):

I found this [tutorial](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Windows_PowerShell_1.0_Essentials) very helpful when I was learning powershell. I haven't gotten all the way through, so I don't know how advanced it gets, but I think it covers things fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

You may read free e-book *PowerShell Succinctly*:

[image]

> **Description**
>
> PowerShell Succinctly highlights some of the PowerShell programming
> model’s many benefits, specifically for .NET developers and system
> administrators. Author Rui Machado guides readers through time-saving
> methods that simplify code testing by eliminating the need to create a
> new application in Visual Studio. Also included are tips for using
> additional services, such as PowerGui, WMI, and SQL Server, to get the
> most out of PowerShell. Even if you don’t already use scripting
> languages to manage your machines, PowerShell Succinctly will show you
> just how easy it is to automate activities, work with databases, and
> interact with a variety of file types with this useful model.
>
> **Table of Contents**
>
> - Basics
> - File System
> - Processes
> - Windows Management Instrumentation
> - Remove PowerShell
> - Structured Files
> - SQL Server and PowerShell
>   Microsoft Office Interop

Link: https://www.syncfusion.com/resources/techportal/details/ebooks/powershell